# Dates and Dynamic SQL error message

Tags: sql-server, date

Using MS SQL 2012.

I am trying to query a set of tables using dynamic SQL and I am passing through the tablename, a start date in the format of dd/MM/yyyy and an end date in the format of dd/MM/yyyy.

My Code is as follows.

```
@tableName nvarchar(50),
@startDate date,
@endDate date

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Query varchar(max)
SET @Query = 'Select * from ''' + @tableName + ''' where Convert(date, Docdate, 103) >= ''' + CAST(@startDate AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''' and Convert(date, Docdate, 103) <= ''' + CAST(@endDate AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''

EXEC @Query

END
```

The Docdate field has a data type of Date and is in the format of yyyy-MM-dd.

I get the following error when I run this stored procedure.

> Incorrect syntax near '/'.

What am I missing?

UPDATE

I am testing the query with the following entries for the variables and I still get the same error.

```
USE [TestDbs]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[getResultSet]
        @tableName = Prices,
        @startDate = 01/02/2016,
        @endDate = 20/02/2016

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Date getting in as yyyy/mm/ddd or something like that? Would explain the '/' in your error.

Comment: @user2050577: What is the datatype of your Docdate column

Comment: The data type is Date

Comment: Changing *EXEC @Query* to *PRINT @Query* will allow you view/validate the dynamic query.

Comment: @user2050577 do you really need to Convert it to specific country format, when `date` is type safe variable? It's not working the other way (you cannot convert all custom country formatted dates into `date` that sql-server is able to execute)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `sp_executesql` and pass proper date parameters to your query, and avoid the need for casting dates to strings at all:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedure
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @StartDate DATE,
    @EndDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
                ' WHERE Docdate >= @StartDateParam 
                AND Docdate <= @EndDateParam';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql 
                    @Query, 
                    N'@startDateParam DATE, @endDateParam DATE', 
                    @StartDateParam = @StartDate, 
                    @EndDateParam = @EndDate;

END
```

I have made a couple of other minor tweaks too:

1. Change the datatype of @TableName from `NVARCHAR(50)` to `SYSNAME` (Synonym for `NVARCHAR(128), the maximum length of an object name)
2. Change the data type of @Query to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` since this is the type `sp_executesql` expects.
3. Wrapped @TableName with `QUOTENAME` to ensure any special characters do not cause an error.
4. If `DocDate` is already a date, then the explicit convert is not necessary so I have removed this.

---

**ADDENDUM**

You may also wish to add some validation to the table name:

```
-- CHECK TABLE NAME IS A VALID TABLE OF VIEW
IF ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(@TableName, 'U'), OBJECT_ID(@TableName, 'V')) IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- HANDLE INVALID NAME
    RETURN;
END
```

**EDIT**

I have changed the procedure slightly to cater for sending through a schema qualified table name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getResultSet
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @StartDate DATE,
    @EndDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' +         
                QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@TableName))) + '.' + 
                QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@TableName))) +
                ' WHERE Docdate >= @StartDateParam 
                AND Docdate <= @EndDateParam';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql 
                    @Query, 
                    N'@startDateParam DATE, @endDateParam DATE', 
                    @StartDateParam = @StartDate, 
                    @EndDateParam = @EndDate;

END
```

Then you would use this to execute it:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[getResultSet]
        @tableName = 'dbo.Prices',
        @startDate = '01/02/2016',
        @endDate = '20/02/2016'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value;
```

Or better still use a culture insensitive date format (yyyyMMdd) for your literals:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[getResultSet]
        @tableName = 'dbo.Prices',
        @startDate = '20160201',
        @endDate = '20160220'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value;
```

Comment: Deleting my answer, this is much better. Is it not better to use `BETWEEN` though? Just for readability?

Comment: I like this answer. But for better security and to avoid SQL injection I would validate table name against catalog views

Comment: @Fred `BETWEEN` would be expanded to use `>= AND <=` during compilation anyway, so there is no performance benefit, so the only thing that would make it "better" is personal preference. I personally never use `BETWEEN`, most of the reasons for this are covered in the article [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @JesúsLópez I though this, but using `QUOTENAME` will handle most of the SQL Injection worries, and it might just be better to let the invalid object name exception caused by executing the query with an invalid table name bubble up to the caller. For the sake of completeness though I have added this to the end.

Comment: Thanks, my query now matches yours exactly.  I am passing through a start date of 01/02/2016 and an end date of 20/02/2016 and I get the same error.  Am I passing in the dates incorrectly.  I have updated my question to include a the execute method of the stored procedure.

Comment: OK I have noticed something.  If I execute the SP in SQL Management studio and put values into the variables it errors as you can see above in my update it isnt putting ' marks around the dates.  If I manually enter these it works???

Comment: You still need to put quote marks around your literals when calling the procedure. See my updated answer for a script that I have now tested.